# elasticsearch applying security on a running cluster

Tags: security, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I've an ELK stack 7.6.2 with logstash, an elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes and kibana. I would like to add security but the only doc I can fin always start 'from scratch' I would like to have an example on an already running cluster in order not te mess up with it. Thanks for your help.
Guillaume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not enable security features on an already running cluster. Security-settings are classified as *static*, meaning that they can not be dynamically updated on the fly:

> **static**:
> These settings must be set at the node level, either in the elasticsearch.yml file, or as an environment variable or on the command line when starting a node. They must be set on every relevant node in the cluster.
>
> **dynamic**:
> These settings can be dynamically updated on a live cluster with the cluster-update-settings API.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/modules.html for reference and for all settings that can be dynamically updated (you won't find security settings there).

Also, from this guide (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-started-enable-security.html) one can tell that you need to stop your running elasticsearch and kibana instances in order to enable security.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm aware of this, my concern is more on the step by step procedure. Should I stop one node, activate security, then start it, wait for cluster to be green. Then same for the others node ? Can a newly secured node stays in the cluster if the others nodes are not secured ?